# Form submission counter in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I have built my own contact form that sends an e-mail on submission with the information that the visitor has populated the form with. I have not used a plugin to create the form because I needed very specific functionality.

The last thing for me to do now is to create a counter that generates a unique number per form submission. This number is to be included as an order number of sorts in the e-mail that is sent from the form.

I have searched extensively, but my knowledge on this subject is limited. I therefore do not know quite what I am looking for. I think I need to do this in the Wordpress database for the number to be persistent.

How I can do this or where to start is the problem for me. Can someone point me towards a way to do this that is possible for a beginner?

All my code is now in a template file that loads on the Wordpress page that shows the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you saved the form inputs as a 'post type' before emailing, not only would you have a record in case the email goes astray, but WP would also generate a unique post id for the form.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would this post ID start from 0 and increase by one for each form submit? Could it display like 0001 and so on?

I am not really sure if a custom post type is what I would need, but it might be. I truly only need a way to keep tabs on the number of times the form is submitted and get that sent with the form inputs by e-mail.

Comment: It would increment together with all other post types - So if you need it to start on 0 and then 1 etc. then you need to add the counter as a meta field in your post on that post type. after that, you can just order by meta.